# How to ensure that string is one of the keys of an object in a prop that accepts string?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Here is the streamlined prop definition of a component from a package (I don't control).

```
interface InputProps {
  name: string,
  value?: string
}
```

Here is the streamlined type definition of my form.

```
interface IForm {
  name: string,
  email: string,
}

type KForm = keyof IForm
```

Here is my code where I deliberately put a wrong string, but it does not show error.

```
...
 <Input name={'emailx' as KForm} />
...
```

I had the following solutions that check the type, but I don't know if any of it is a good practice.

1. Self-executing function

```
...
 <Input name={((k: KForm)=>k)('email')} />
...
```

2. Same as above, but separate it elsewhere.

```
const getFieldName = (k: KForm) => k;

...
 <Input name={getFieldName('email')} />
...
```

3. Declare separate variable.

```
const emailField: KForm = 'email';
...
 <Input name={emailField} />
...
```

4. A wrapper component.

```
interface WrapperInputProp extends InputProp {
  name: KForm
}
...
<WrapperInput name={'email'} />
```

Edit:

Performance test says negligible difference.

https://jsbench.me/0cl7gvw0g1/1

Comment: Can't you change the prop type in the component?

Comment: I would go for the wrapper component and move on.

Comment: @kelly  It's a component from MUI. I believe I can't, or maybe I am missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 4 is the best in my opinion followed by option 3.
Both of these provide static type checking at transpile time.

Comment: We'll go for wrapper function then. Thanks!